# R: No duplicate keys, data won't spread

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr, reshape2

I'm trying to reshape a data set from long to wide on two keys. I keep getting the message `Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length`.

My dataset looks like this:

```
 School.Name                                    var val    year
 1 A G COX MIDDLE American.Indian.Alaska.Native.Students   3 2010-11
 2 A G COX MIDDLE American.Indian.Alaska.Native.Students   1 2011-12
 3 A G COX MIDDLE American.Indian.Alaska.Native.Students   2 2012-13
 4 A G COX MIDDLE American.Indian.Alaska.Native.Students   3 2013-14
 5 A G COX MIDDLE American.Indian.Alaska.Native.Students   1 2014-15
 6 A G COX MIDDLE American.Indian.Alaska.Native.Students   0 2015-16
```

The original variables had year names in them (formatted as `race.year`, so I had `white.2012_13`, `white.2013_14`, etc.). The first step I took was formatting from wide to long, and pulling year from the variable name. I want my data set to be organized by school and year, with individual demographic categories as variables, and counts as the values. I've been using dcast as such:

`dcast(dem, School.Name + year ~ var, value.var = "val")`

But I'm only getting the length. All help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not getting any error with this data and your code. Can you provide a full reproducible example of the problem?

Comment: Did you try `reshape2::dcast(df,School.Name + year ~ var,sum,value.var="val")`?

Comment: Have you tried `tidyr::spread()`?